# construct two non-homeomorphic topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Construct two topological spaces $X,Y$ satisfying that $X$ is not homeomorphic to $Y$, but $X\times[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $Y\times[0,1]$

i just solve the condition with $[0,1)$. Have no good idea of this construction.

Any idea is helpful. thanks

Comment: Yes, for $[0,1)$ as the second factor, $X=[0,1)$ and $Y=[0,1]$ work, as a well known example. There are metric examples for $[0,1]$ too, though I don’t remember them now.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I hope I'm not missing something, but $[0,1)\times [0,1]$ is not compact unlike $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, so they're not homeomorphic.

Comment: @Scientifica That's right, but $[0,1] \times [0,1)$ and $[0,1) \times [0,1)$ are. The second factor $[0,1)$ case.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Oh ok sry I missunderstood. Thank you.

Comment: @Scientifica Ok, I was just referring to the OP mentioning he already did the $[0,1)$ case, which is classical.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Indeed I see.

Comment: Take the same circle for all $t\in[0,1]$ for $(X,t)$ and the $t^{\rm th}$ part of a circle for $(Y,t)$.  Does that work?